# Inverse of math.atan2?

Tags: math, lua, trigonometry

What is the inverse of the function

```
math.atan2
```

I use this in Lua where I can get the inverse of `math.atan` by `math.tan`.
But I am lost here.

**EDIT**

OK, let me give you more details.

I needed to calculate angle between 2 points (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) and I did,

```
local dy = y1-y2 
local dx = x1-x2
local angle = atan2(dy,dx)* 180 / pi
```

Now if I have the angle, is it possible to get back dy and dx?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Given only the angle you can only derive a unit vector pointing to `(dx, dy)`. To get the original `(dx, dy)` you also need to know the length of the vector `(dx, dy)`, which I'll call `len`.  You also have to convert the angle you derived from degrees back to radians and then use the trig equations mentioned elsewhere in this post. That is you have:

```
local dy = y1-y2
local dx = x1-x2
local angle = atan2(dy,dx) * 180 / pi
local len = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
```

Given `angle` (in degrees) and the vector length, `len`, you can derive `dx` and `dy` by:

```
local theta = angle * pi / 180
local dx = len * cos(theta)
local dy = len * sin(theta)
```

Comment: In Lua you can use `math.deg` and `math.rad` to convert between degrees and radians.

Comment: @lhf:  Thanks. I've never done anything in lua, so I thought this approach would be safe.

Comment: import math, followed by: theta = math.radians(angle)

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, something like this will help:

```
x = cos(theta)
y = sin(theta)
```

Simple Google search threw this up, and the guy who asked the question said it solved it.

Comment: Yeah I saw that too.  Do you know what the x and y values (calculated by sin and cos) indicate with respect to my question  (I have updated the question) ?

Comment: Make sure `theta` is in radians, The code given by the OP converts to degrees.

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably get the wrong numbers if you use:

```
local dy = y1-y2 
local dx = x1-x2
local angle = atan2(dy,dx) * 180 / pi
```

If you are using the coordinate system where y gets bigger going down the screen and x gets bigger going to the right then you should use:

```
local dy = y1 - y2
local dx = x2 - x1
local angle = math.deg(math.atan2(dy, dx))
if (angle < 0) then
  angle = 360 + angle
end
```

The reason you want to use this is because atan2 in lua will give you a number between -180 and 180. It will be correct until you hit 180 then as it should go beyond 180 (i.e. 187) it will invert it to a negative number going down from -180 to 0 as you get closer to 360. To correct for this we check to see if the angle is less than 0 and if it is we add 360 to give us the correct angle.

Answer (score 0):

According [this reference](http://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/math.atan2):

> Returns the arc tangent of y/x (in radians), but uses the signs of
>   both parameters to find the quadrant of the result. (It also handles
>   correctly the case of x being zero.)

So I guess you can use `math.tan` to invert it also.

Answer (score 0):

As atan2 works as tan-1, so the inverse could be tan, taking into consideration conversion between radian and degree